# angularjs directive binding function with argument

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to send function with argument to angularjs directive.
because this directive is always use just one own variable.
and function that controller send to directive is doing with that variable.

I make controller like below

```
app.controller('TestController', function($scope) {
    $scope.args = ['arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3', 'arg4', 'arg5'];
    $scope.makeDirectiveFunction = makeDirectiveFunction;

    function iWantDoThisInDirective(arg, content) {
        alert(arg + content);
    }

    // Controller make function with 'arg'
    // and return function that have 'content' parameter
    // finally doing controller function with 'arg' and 'content' argument
    function makeDirectiveFunction(arg) {
        return function editorFunc(content) {
            iWantDoThisInDirective(arg, content);
        }
    }
});
```

I want execute 'itIsControllerFunction' with 'arg' and 'content' arguments. so I make a function 'makeDirectiveFunction' to make function that has 'content' parameter.

This is view(index.html)

```
<div ng-repeat="arg in args">
    <redactor do-func="makeDirectiveFunction(arg)"></redactor>
</div>
```

And this is directive

```
app.directive('redactor', function($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: {
            doFunc: '=',
        },
        template: '<button ng-click="doInDirective()">Register!</button>',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.doInDirective = function() {
                var content = "I'm in directive!";
                scope.doFunc(content);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

It is work well, but console show **infdig error**

```
Error: $rootScope:infdig
Infinite $digest Loop
10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: [[{"msg":"fn: function (c,e,f,g){f=d&&g?g[0]:a(c,e,f,g);return b(f,c,e)}"}],[{"msg":"fn: function (c,e,f,g){f=d&&g?g[0]:a(c,e,f,g);return b(f,c,e)}"}],[{"msg":"fn: function (c,e,f,g){f=d&&g?g[0]:a(c,e,f,g);return b(f,c,e)}"}],[{"msg":"fn: function (c,e,f,g){f=d&&g?g[0]:a(c,e,f,g);return b(f,c,e)}"}],[{"msg":"fn: function (c,e,f,g){f=d&&g?g[0]:a(c,e,f,g);return b(f,c,e)}"}]]
```

Maybe it's caused nested return function, but I cannot solve it.
I hope you'll help. thanks.

Comment: can you provide a fiddle or plunkr

Answer (score 0):

First thing first, when you pass a function to a directive use

```
scope: {
    doFunc: '&',
}
```

instead of

```
scope: {
    doFunc: '=',
}
```

From the [source](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#creating-a-directive-that-adds-event-listeners)

> Best Practice: use &attr in the scope option when you want your directive to expose an API for binding to behaviors

Secondly: Because you are returning a function you need a second pair of brackets to call the inner function, please see below:

```
scope.doInDirective = function() {
    var content = "I'm in directive!";
    scope.doFunc()(content);
}
```

Please see working example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/tjaart/fej6g82v/1/)

Complete code:

```
<div ng-controller="TestController as vm">
  <div ng-repeat="arg in args">
    <redactor do-func="makeDirectiveFunction(arg)"></redactor>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var myApp = angular.module('application', []);

myApp.controller('TestController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.args = ['arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3', 'arg4', 'arg5'];
  $scope.makeDirectiveFunction = makeDirectiveFunction;

  function iWantDoThisInDirective(arg, content) {
    alert(arg + content);
  }

  // Controller make function with 'arg'
  // and return function that have 'content' parameter
  // finally doing controller function with 'arg' and 'content' argument
  function makeDirectiveFunction(arg) {
    return function editorFunc(content) {
      iWantDoThisInDirective(arg, content);
    }
  }
}]).directive('redactor', function($timeout) {
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    scope: {
      doFunc: '&doFunc',
    },
    template: '<button ng-click="doInDirective()">Register!</button>',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.doInDirective = function() {
        var content = "I'm in directive!";
        scope.doFunc()(content);
      }
    }
  }
});
```